# Create a plane with curved edges using PlaneGeometry - Three.js

Tags: three.js, plane

I'm trying to create a 2D square with curved/round edges. As I understand it using planes is the way to go. I'm struggling to figure out how exactly to do this though. It seems like it should be simple. Can't seem to find any straightforward answers online either so I would really appreciate the help.

```
// Create plane
let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1)
// Round the edges somehow?
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
this.mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2
this.container.add(this.mesh)
```

[image: This is what im going for except filled in]

Comment: Easiest way is to assign a transparent texture with the shape you need to the plane. Threejs only makes square geometries, there’s no built-in method to round corners or cut out the inside to make it hollow.

Comment: Using of `THREE.Shape()` and `THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry()` seems an option. https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shapes#webgl_geometry_shapes

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Ill give each method a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get it working based off @prisoner849 suggestion to use THREE.Shape() and THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(). Posting my answer but its mostly the same as the found here [here](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shapes#webgl_geometry_shapes)

```
let x = 1; let y = 1; let width = 50; let height = 50; let radius = 20
        
let shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo( x, y + radius );
shape.lineTo( x, y + height - radius );
shape.quadraticCurveTo( x, y + height, x + radius, y + height );
shape.lineTo( x + width - radius, y + height );
shape.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius );
shape.lineTo( x + width, y + radius );
shape.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y, x + width - radius, y );
shape.lineTo( x + radius, y );
shape.quadraticCurveTo( x, y, x, y + radius );

let geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );

this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
this.mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2
this.container.add(this.mesh)
```